# Exporting / Importing C++ Functions from Linux Dynamic Library / Linux Console App | Visual Studio Linux Projects

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, visual-c++, shared-libraries

I would like to export global C++ functions from a Linux C++ `.so` shared object library and consume those functions in a Linux C++ `.out` application.

I have looked at some examples of how this is typically done in a Linux development environment. However I am using Visual Studio Linux projects and the new [Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e) extension. I believe many of the steps of the examples I have seen will be taken care of by the Visual Studio build system so things appear to be a little different in this situation.

I have created two Linux C++ projects in Visual Studio, one empty project which I have changed to be a `.so` in the properties and a console app. I have referenced the shared object library in the console app.

The shared object library project has two files, `functions.h` and `functions.cpp`.

functions.h

```
#pragma once
void Function_01();
```

functions.cpp

```
#include functions.h
extern "C" void Function_01() {
    return 0;
}
```

I have added the `functions.h` file to the consuming console app...

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    Function_01();
    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps exporting global functions seems odd but for my problem this seems the most natural approach, I intend to wrap the functions in a namespace once the library is building and linking.

What am I doing wrong? How do I link these Visual C++ for Linux Development projects and consume functions exported from the shared object library?

Comment: This *may* be relevant: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Answer (score 0):

Library functions are exported by default so you simply call them in your code and link against the library when you build the application with gcc. You're aiming for a command line that looks something like:

```
g++ -o myprog myprog.cpp -lfunctions -L/home/test/projects/mylibs
```

where:

- myprog is the executable for your console application that you can run from the command line with `./myprog`
- `functions` refers to your shared object library which is a file named libfunctions.so ('lib' and '.so' are automatically pre- and appended)
- libfunctions.so can be found in folder /home/test/projects/mylibs

In Visual C++ for Linux Development (VCLinux) you will specify the name of the library, `functions` , in the project settings under Linker / Input / Library Dependencies and the path to the folder where the library can be found in under Linker / General / Additional Library Directories. I.e. just as you would when linking a DLL with a Windows application.

VCLinux provides a development environment that will be familiar to Visual Studio users. But it's worth noting that, while VCLinux generates g++ commands to compile and link your application, whatever you have learned about building applications on Linux with gcc very much applies. Although you could skip over the makefile chapters for now.

Also be aware that VCLinux is very much a work in progress. There are several issues around debugging shared libraries particularly using a test console application - more information can be found on the [VCLinux GitHub project page](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux) . You are encouraged to be positive and contribute constructive feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I couldn't get your example to work, possibly because it's a shared library which I am linking to and the `-lfunctions` option seems to be for static `.a` libraries. I found that specifying the full path to the `libFuntions.so.1.0` library on the command line worked. In visual studio this corresponds to entering the full path in Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. However I need to debug into the linked Shared Object library. Debugging into the library is not enabled in current setup... Any ideas on how to enable debugging into the shared object library?

Comment: Linking to a shared library is the same as a static library. It's the combination of `-L` for path and `-l` for library name that you need to get right. I recommend you increase output verbosity and examine the compiler and linker command lines. You should find that the way you have done it and my suggestions are actually the same. [Details here:](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/#verbose)  .

Comment: To step into a shared library with the debugger in VCLinux you have to debug in gdb mode (in which gdb runs entirely on the remote system). See Debugging / Debugging Mode in project settings. This has issues of its own which have been raised on the [VCLinux GitHub project site](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux) .